# Getting some prefix or postfix characters with message

Tags: apache-kafka

i am new in kafka and i have created a sample consumer in java for getting data from kafka topic but when i consuming the message, arrives with additional string or characters like with some special characters (?????Xmydata) like this.

if i am not using right code please provide me appropriate code.

```
The code i am using..

        getting output = ?????mydata
        expected output = mydata 




         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
                props.put("group.id", "mysql-joined-datalist2");
                props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
                props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
                props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

                //kafka consumer object
                KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

                //subscribe to topic
                consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("mysql-joined-datalist2"));

                //infinite poll loop
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(0);
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                        String payload = record.value();
        //                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        String oldString = record.value();
                        String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
                        System.out.println("newString : " + newString);
                        String s2 = new String(record.value().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
                         System.out.println("str : "+s2); // output = str : ?????Xmydata
        }



        please help me. thanks in advanced.
```

Comment: What is the source of the data in the Kafka topic - what serialisation format is it using?

Comment: i  want to read messages from mysql database so source would be mysql database.

Comment: So the problem you're _currently_ getting…how are you getting that data into the topic _currently_? What serialisation method is it using?

Comment: Are you talking about...

Comment: props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

Comment: You're *consuming* data - where did that data originate onto the topic *from*? What application or process put it there? You've listed the *de*serialiser, what what the _serialiser_ for the data in the first place?

Comment: my source file configuration is..

Comment: name=mysql-whitelist-timestamp-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://183.82.3.61:3306/kafka_test?user=root&password=root
mode=timestamp+incrementing
query=select * from userstates
timestamp.column.name=created_date
incrementing.column.name=state_id 
topic.prefix=mysql-joined-datalist2
poll.interval.ms = 5000

Comment: i have just add my config details in  source-quickstart-sqlite.properties to put data onto the topic from database.  and i want to sink that topic's data into my csv file.